# Best way to read zip file in PHP

Tags: php, zip

`file_get_contents("zip:///a/b/c.zip")` is returning `NULL`. How can I read unzipped contents of a zip file in PHP 5+?

Answer (score 9):

use `ZipArchive` class

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open('test.zip');
echo $zip->getFromName('filename.txt');
$zip->close();
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `zip_open` and `zip_read` functions to do it.
Documentation to it you can find at http://php.net/manual/en/function.zip-read.php

```
<?php
/**
* This method unzips a directory within a zip-archive
*
* @author Florian 'x!sign.dll' Wolf
* @license LGPL v2 or later
* @link http://www.xsigndll.de
* @link http://www.clansuite.com
*/

function extractZip( $zipFile = '', $dirFromZip = '' )
{   
    define(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, '/');

    $zipDir = getcwd() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $zip = zip_open($zipDir.$zipFile);

    if ($zip)
    {
        while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip))
        {
            $completePath = $zipDir . dirname(zip_entry_name($zip_entry));
            $completeName = $zipDir . zip_entry_name($zip_entry);

            // Walk through path to create non existing directories
            // This won't apply to empty directories ! They are created further below
            if(!file_exists($completePath) && preg_match( '#^' . $dirFromZip .'.*#', dirname(zip_entry_name($zip_entry)) ) )
            {
                $tmp = '';
                foreach(explode('/',$completePath) AS $k)
                {
                    $tmp .= $k.'/';
                    if(!file_exists($tmp) )
                    {
                        @mkdir($tmp, 0777);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry, "r"))
            {
                if( preg_match( '#^' . $dirFromZip .'.*#', dirname(zip_entry_name($zip_entry)) ) )
                {
                    if ($fd = @fopen($completeName, 'w+'))
                    {
                        fwrite($fd, zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry)));
                        fclose($fd);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // We think this was an empty directory
                        mkdir($completeName, 0777);
                    }
                    zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
                }
            }
        }
        zip_close($zip);
    }
    return true;
}

// The call to exctract a path within the zip file
extractZip( 'clansuite.zip', 'core/filters' );
?>
```

Comment: `if ($zip)` doesn't work, you should use `if (is_resource($zip))`. See [`zip_open`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.zip-open.php). Also, the link provided in the answer is not available anymore.

Comment: Do not use zip_open/zip_read/etc - **These functions have been DEPRECATED as of PHP 8.0.0**. Relying on this function is highly discouraged. Use ZipArchive instead.

Answer (score 2):

look at the build in zip functions:
http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php

Comment: I like the "ZipArchive" class.

Answer (score 1):

The `zip://` protocol is provided by the [ZIP extension](http://www.php.net/zip) of PHP. Check in your `phpinfo()` output whether the extension has been installed or not.

Comment: from phpinfo(): 

Zip => enabled

Extension Version => $Id: php_zip.c,v 1.1.2.38 2007/08/06 22:02:32 bjori Exp $

Zip version => 2.0.0

Libzip version => 0.7.1

Registered PHP Streams => zip, php, file, data, http, ftp, compress.bzip2, compress.zlib, https, ftps

Comment: Have you checked if the file you try to open is actually a valid `.zip` file?

Comment: %> file test.zip
test.zip: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract

Comment: Code snippet: $data = file_get_contents('zip:///path/to/file/test.zip', FALSE, NULL, 0, 1024); The $data is NULL I am verified 1. permissions 2. whether its a proper .zip format. Can zip files be read this way???

Comment: Forgot to mention the zip file always contains a single file.

Answer (score 1):

I know this message is old but I had the same problem and I found a solution with the PHP library [ZipArchive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php).

So I share :)

```
// Initialization
$zipFilename = "example.zip";

// Object Creation
$zipObject  = new ZipArchive();

// If File Open
if ($zipObject->open($zipFilename)===true)
{
    // Getting Number of Files in ZIP
    $nbFile = $zipObject->numFiles;

    // For each file in ZIP
    for ($i = 0; $i < $nbFile; $i++)
    {
        // Getting File Name
        $filename = $zipObject->getNameIndex($i);

        // Getting Content
        $content = file_get_contents("zip://".$zipFilename."#".$filename);
    
        // Display Infos
        echo "<br /><b>".$filename."</b>";
        echo "<br />".$content."<br />";
    }
    // End - For Each File in ZIP

    // Close File
    $zipObject->close();
}
// End - If File Open
```

Answer (score 0):

I am responding to the first part of the question i.e. using the file_get_contents method
*'file_get_contents("zip:///a/b/c.zip")'* Usually that method is used to read one particular file nested inside the zip file. In order to extract all the contents; others have given nice answers.

I am using PHP 7.2.34 on windows and later on in Linux. I kept a zip file at d:\data and this syntax works in windows. It *does* echo the contents of example1.py which is inside a "folder" in the ZIP file.

Possibly it is also to do with where/how the zip file was created. When I had created the zip file from within PHP, the internal delimiters were backslashes but when Windows created the zip file (by using the "Send to compressed folder" feature in Windows explorer) then Windows was using the Linux convention inside the zip file!

More testing is needed here to know which delimiter for the internal paths, is being used in the zip file

```
    <?php
    $str = file_get_contents('zip://d:/data/demo.zip#examples\\example1.py');
    echo $str;
    ?>
```