# Extracting ZIP file directories - PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, zip, directory

I want the user to be able to upload a ZIP file of images or a single image. The directories will be stored in a zip_upload file and the single images in another. I have mastered the upload process. But the problem comes when storing the files and directories on the server.

A problematic scenario:

A user uploads a .zip file named A, containing 2 directories, one called B, the other, C. My question is how can I check whether there are any other directories that have the same name as either B or C. Take note that I'm not storing A as a directory, but the inner directories, B and C.

I've been using the [PHP Zip Extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php)

My current code:

```
if($continue == "zip"){
  $target_path = "/var/www/....".$filename;
  // change this to the correct site path
  echo "target: ".$target_path."<br/>";
  //if directory already exists
  //say that it already exists, please try again
  $flag = 1;
//else
  //upload the file
  //$flag = 0;
if($flag == 1){
  if(move_uploaded_file($source, $target_path)) {
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $x = $zip->open($target_path);
    if ($x === true) {
      $zip->extractTo("/var/www/...");
      // change this to the correct site path
      $zip->close();
      unlink($target_path);
    }
    $message = "Your .zip file was uploaded and unpacked.";
  } else {
    $message = "There was a problem with the upload. Please try again.";
  }
} else {
  $message = "Already a directory called ".$filename. ". Please rename and retry. Note: Please rename the folder within the zip file.";
}
```

Can anyone point me to a solution or alternative to do what I want?

Comment: Are you aware of the security issues with allowing users to upload a *.zip file?

Comment: Yes, definitely i'm just delivering the fundamental process first

Comment: Are you looking for `file_exists`? http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Comment: Maybe, but how can I do that on the directories B and C in the description above?

Comment: use [this anwser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3599093/443685) which unzip(s) files one by one. so meanwhile you can check directory existance (or whatever)