# Get content of a zip file and echo it to user

Tags: php

I wanna make a link for download and all of my file is zip but idont want to my user knows where is my download link

so i wanna get content of zip file and echo it with zip header to user can download it how can i do this?

Comment: Check this question and it's answers! [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599056/best-way-to-read-zip-file-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a "download.php?get=". base64_encode($filename)
When the user click on "download zip", you redirect him with header("Location: download.php?get=". base64_encode($url) to that page.
The headers, here we go

```
$filename = base64_decode($_GET[get]);
$filepath = "/var/www/domain/httpdocs/download/path/";

header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filepath.$filename));
ob_end_flush();
@readfile($filepath.$filename);
```

Comment: P.s. if you want to make the download link unique, just add "&u=base64_encode(time())", then decode the string and limit the download accessibility to let's say 10 minutes.

Comment: my firend i try this but when file is ready for download its show 0 bytes i sure my destination (filepath is ok ) ....

Answer (score 0):

Instead of experimenting with headers you could try downloading some 'ready for use' [php class](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpeasydownload/). Then your could do something like:

```
$fileDown = new PHPFileDownload(null, null, 'myFileName', null, 'mypath/myfile.txt');
$fileDown->exportData();
```