# read contents of zipped files through file_get_contents in codeigniter in .srt format and upload to server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to read contents of zipped file as

```
$subda=file_get_contents('http://www.yifysubtitles.com/subtitle/thewilbyconspiracy1975dvdripxvid-english-128250.zip');
```

And trying to upload at my online server as below

```
$this->load->library('zip');
$data = $subda;
$name = 'myfile.srt';
$this->zip->add_data($name, $data);
$this->zip->archive('assets/subtitles/myzipfile.zip');
```

But when I check this uploaded file at my server it does not compressed properly.
it does not contain any data.

when I echo $subda it give results like.
[image]

Where I am wrong...
through file_get_contents I am already getting contents of zip file.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do:

```
$subda=file_get_contents('http://www.yifysubtitles.com/subtitle/thewilbyconspiracy1975dvdripxvid-english-128250.zip');
```

This will just load the ZIP content into the string rather than uncompressed.

See this on how you can read using a lib in php:

[Best way to read zip file in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599056/best-way-to-read-zip-file-in-php)

Comment: how can i get zip file from remote server into a php variable. what function should i use in place of file_get_contents.

Comment: Did you click on the link above? It clearly mentions how and what to do?